# Redireccionar con slash

Tags: .htaccess

buen día comunidad, tengo un problema con el htaccess y me que me ayuden, ante manos muchas gracias.

```
necesito direccionamiento todos los links que estan sin slsh con slsh, me explico:

entrada del link: dominio.com/hotel
quiero que siempre entre con slsh: dominio.com/hotel/
```

osea: si le pongo siempre sin / que el ponga siempre el /

gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```